# How do I measure the length of the scale bar in pixel point?

Tags: python

[scalebar.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5HlT.png)

How do I measure the length of the scale bar in pixel point, which is only the white area in the picture?

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open("scalebar.png")
width, height = im.size
print(width, height)
```

638 58

`scalebar=io.imshow('scalebar.png')`

```
profile=np.mean(scalebar[31:34,:],axis=0)
pixels=np.arange(1,np.size(profile)+1,1)
```

TypeError: 'AxesImage' object is not subscriptable

```
plt.plot(pixels,profile)
plt.xlabel('Pixels')
plt.ylabel('Intensity');
```

this is what I am trying to do.

Comment: what is `io`? It is probably not the "Core tools for working with streams".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `imshow('scalebar.png')` it will return a handle to the figure, and not the data. You can simply convert the image data directly to a numpy array.

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

im = Image.open("scalebar.png")
width, height = im.size
print(width, height)

scalebar = np.asarray(im)
profile = np.mean(scalebar[31:34,:],axis=0)
pixels = np.arange(1,np.size(profile)+1,1)
plot(pixels, profile)
```

Comment: Could you accept the answer if you found it useful?